# Create an internal search engine with Elasticsearch on symfony2

Tags: symfony, elasticsearch, doctrine

I am about to create an internal search engine for a website using elasticsearch, mainly because we really have a lot of records on mysql (around 10M) and we want to take advantage of the full text search.

We are currently using doctrine with mysql, so I have an entity for a specific type of information, and when searching on mysql I use to pass an array of this entities to the template.

so far so good.

My question is mostly regarding the best practice to use for this specific task.

Should I have to search on ES and then pass the results to the template in some way (still need to decide how) or can I simply search and get the ids of the records I need from ES and then create my entities from mysql and pass them to the template? the second option is probably easier and I could save on ES only the data I want to perform the search on.

thanks

M

Answer (score 0):

Give a try to [FOSElasticaBundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSElasticaBundle). It's a high-quality library built on top of Elastica that basically implements your second option.

It allows to map fields of your Doctrine entities in ES indexes, automatically re-index documents when they are updated through Doctrine and return instances of Doctrine entities when you do an ES search query.

Comment: I wasn't able to make elasticabundle work with ES2.2 and symfony 2.8, maybe some compatibility problem,  but I already created the abstraction to use the ES php API. I need the information below to decide which fields exactly to replicate and sync on ES...

Comment: You can use this experimental branch: https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSElasticaBundle/pull/1002